# What intuitive axioms are equivalent to the axiom of regularity?

Tags: set-theory

So, I'm currently taking a set theory course. I understand the axiom of regularity or foundation, and why it was added, but I can't help but get the feeling that it's too strong. I know it rules out stuff like $x\in x$ or $x\in y$ and $y\in x$. My question is, are there axioms that are more intuitive, along the lines of ruling out these cases, which are equivalent to the axiom of regularity, under the other axioms of ZFC?

Comment: Which statement of regularity are you using?

Comment: I quite like V = WF - i.e. the cumulative hierarchy captures every set.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to rule out $x\in x$, etc. It never seems to come up everyday mathematics. And you really don't need to do so to avoid the contradictions of naive set theory, e.g. Russell's Paradox.

Answer (score 3):

You can use $\textbf{There exists a rank function}$. Namely there is a formula $\varphi(x,\alpha)$ which is true if and only if $\alpha$ is an ordinal, and $\alpha=\sup\{\beta+1\mid\exists y\in x\varphi(y,\beta)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no infinite sequence of sets $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ such that $x_1\ni x_2\ni x_3\ni\ldots$ The equivalence to the axiom of regularity requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: While it is true in ZFC, well-foundedness is stronger than just no decreasing sequence without the axiom of choice. That been said, I am not sure that in the case of $\in$ it is true; i.e. it might be provable from the above that $\in$ is well-founded even in ZF.

Comment: @Asaf You need something like DC to iteratively get $in$-smaller-and-smaller elements in case regularity is violated.

Comment: I think that DC is equivalent to the equivalency between the forms of well-foundedness (it certainly implies it). But it is consistent that there are non-well founded relations without decreasing chains. My point was that it might be provable that if such set exists then there is one with an actual decreasing chain, in which case ZF-Reg is enough to prove the equivalence in the case of the $\in$ relation.

Comment: @Asaf I'm not sure I get your point. Is something wrong in my answer?

Comment: No, not at all. The question also specified ZFC-Reg as the theory. But I wanted to point out that well-foundedness is not equivalent to the lack of decreasing sequences without some form of choice. I also added that in the particular case of $\in$ it might be provable after all, but I don't know for sure. :-)

Comment: @Asaf I see, I see...

Comment: I forgot to tell you, I delegated the problem to someone who was inclined to verify this and indeed you need the axiom of choice to prove in ZF-Reg the $in$ is well-founded if and only if it has no decreasing chains.

Comment: @Asaf Cool. Your delegate verified this by pulling a reference out of his/her hat, or by constructing (relating to) a model on the spot?

Comment: Oh, it's one of my teachers from BGU who was giving a course on axiomatic set theory at the time, so he was fresh on constructing permutation models in which regularity is negated. We conjectured that a certain approach might have the wanted results and later that week he told me that he verified this indeed was the case.

Comment: @Asaf That's kinda cool.

Comment: Yes, it is very cool. I am planning to write a note summarizing this method (which I believe is due to Mostowski), and I might use this as an example. But from planning to do there is a huge gap in time. :-)